# Can we use reduced relative forms in formal context?

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis

I know that I can omit the italic part below in daily speech or casual writing. Is it against formality to omit such things in, for example, an article or essay?

> Research *(that is)* led by the Museum of London has revealed two more individuals of Asian ancestry, buried among the remains of other citizens of ancient Londinium.

Comment: I think that it's safe to omit it, even in formal speech. Only a pedant would pick you up on it these days. Maybe this is a good question for the grown-ups in English.SE.

Comment: @MickSharpe It's a common or garden variety ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

You may omit "that is" from a sentence like this in formal writing, and you should.

Reason: in formal writing, this type of conciseness is good.  It helps the reader focus on your ideas, rather than getting distracted by your sentence structure concerns.